# How to create tlp different profiles?

Tags: tlp

I would like to create different TLP profiles (Battery saving, Balanced and Performance), but can't figure out what things I need to change in the configuration file. Googling hasn't helped me to find out any guide for that either. Any idea which lines in the configuration files I need to change apart from the CPU? For writing I'd like the battery saving profile and for studying the balanced one, while for gaming the performance profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way. TLP supports only two profiles, BAT and AC.

(I'm the author)

Comment: Is there is a way to force any of the profile?

Comment: That's really unfortunate. Would be nice to have multiple profiles. For example Quite and Loud profile. Even on AC yo can want to have reduced fan speed. 

To be more precise. I'm currently experiencing issues with power. I am forced to connect my laptop to external battery. So I am forced to limit power usage. But system has no idea it is battery, it thinks it's AC but it is actually DC car battery. So I need two profiles -- on to save as much resources regardless of power source, and one -- normal, and third -- gaming, with not reducing performance a lit even on battery.